# Загрузить данные из списка в одну колонку БД(продолжение)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Уже задавала вопрос и мне помогли,получилось сделать колонку из цикла. Никак не получается сделать еще одну..Данные для l выводятся([(i,) for i in l]), а как вывести для l2 в отдельном столбце(ID2)..И как правильно вписать Код:

```
import sqlite3
import random

k=0
n=''
l=[]
l2=[]

while k<30:
    n=str(random.randint(1000000000000,9234567891011))
    f=str(random.randint(100,900))
    k+=1
    l+=str(n).split()
    l2+=str(f).split()

conn = sqlite3.connect("Mydata.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE albums( ID,ID2)""")

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO albums VALUES (?,?)",[(i,) for i in l])

conn.commit()
```

Comment: `... VALUES (?,?)", [(x,y) for x,y in zip(l, l2)])`

Comment: `... VALUES (?,?)", zip(l, l2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще и эффективнее сразу подготовить список кортежей (каждый кортеж соответствует одной записи в таблице) с данными, которые вы хотите вставить в SQL таблицу:

```
data = []

for _ in range(30):
    n=str(random.randint(1000000000000,9234567891011))
    f=str(random.randint(100,900))
    data.append((n, f))

conn = sqlite3.connect("c:/temp/Mydata.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE albums( ID,ID2)""")

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO albums VALUES (?,?)", data)
```

Comment: Супер!! Все получилось!! Вы мне очень помогли

Comment: @Елена, всегда рад помочь)